# amp-next-page JSON Configuration: optional field "next" does not working

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to implement the following example based on amp-next-page docs [Load configuration from a remote URL](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-next-page/#load-configuration-from-a-remote-url)

```
// index.html
<script async custom-element="amp-next-page" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-next-page-1.0.js"></script>
{...}
<amp-next-page src="https://example.com/next-page-config.json"></amp-next-page>
```

```
// next-page-config.json response:
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "image": "https://example.com/image1.jpg",
      "title": "This article shows first",
      "url": "https://example.com/article1.amp.html"
    },
    {
      "image": "https://example.com/image2.jpg",
      "title": "This article shows second",
      "url": "https://example.com/article2.amp.html"
    }
  ],
  "next": "https://example.com/more-pages.json"
}
```

```
// more-pages.json response:
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "image": "https://example.com/image3.jpg",
      "title": "Last article",
      "url": "https://example.com/article3.amp.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result expected:

1. Render index.html
2. GET https://example.com/next-page-config.json
3. Render pages (article1, article2, article3)
4. GET https://example.com/more-pages.json
5. Render pages (article3)
6. End

Result obtained:

1. Render index.html
2. GET https://example.com/next-page-config.json
3. Render pages (article1, article2, article3)
4. End

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, or this optional field "next" doesn't works

There are a real example of amp-next-page (v1.0) using the "next" field in json response?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, it was hard to find a solution for this issue, but I did.

The "next" attribute does not work, don't matter what. So I tried to bring 100 articles at the same time and it didn't work either. It did bring the recommendation boxes, but the next pages haven't been loaded. However, I realized that the next pages only load when the current user scrolls the view until the end of the page.

So I got the solution. I just have to hide (display: none) the majority of the elements (recommendation boxes) until the user achieves the end of the screen, so the next page could be loaded. It finally did work.

So my .json file returns more than 100 articles and I hide them using the following CSS:

```
.amp-next-page-link:nth-of-type(1n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```